# Frames issue using Watir-Webdriver and phantomjs

Tags: selenium, watir, watir-webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I'm writing test using Watir-Webdriver and phantomjs and I've got an issue with iframes. 
I'm trying to get an element with the following code:

```
browser.frame(:index => 0).div(:id, "wrapper").exists?
```

and when I'm using phantomjs, it raise an error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Watir::FramedDriver::UnknownFrameException
```

but when I'm using chrome driver, the code above works properly and returns "true" value.

Any ideas how can I fix it? Or maybe there is any other way to get this element using phantomjs?
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that ghostdriver does not have support for frames. I could not find an open issue related to frames in it's bug tracker: https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues If you think it is a bug in ghostdriver, you should report it there.

Comment: Okay, so I'll report this issue. Thank you for the really quick answer.

Comment: It should work properly. Only frame spec which has been guarded in watirspec is related with nested frames (https://github.com/watir/watirspec/blob/master/frame_spec.rb#L67-L75). Other specs are passing. So it seems to be something more specific.